# resend same region to R shell in emacs

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I am using emacs in ESS mode. Often times I find myself executing the same region of source code many times, so I need select the region then use the "send region" binding. Selecting the same region repeatedly, with mouse or keyboard, is the bottleneck I would like to cut out. Is there a way to resend the last sent region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESS comes bundled with a bunch of eval commands, check `ess-inf` for all the options.  I don't see one for resending a region sent via `ess-eval-region`, but it shouldn't be too hard to add that functionality.

For example, you can cache the start/end positions used by a previous call of `ess-eval-region` by hooking that function and making some local variables.  Then, just recall `ess-eval-region` with the cached values.

```
;; cache region start and end position when `ess-eval-region' is called
(defadvice ess-eval-region (before ess-cache-region activate)
  (setq-local ess--last-region-beg (ad-get-arg 0))
  (setq-local ess--last-region-end (ad-get-arg 1)))

(defun ess-eval-last-region (toggle)
  "Resend last region sent by `ess-eval-region'"
  (interactive "P")
  (when (bound-and-true-p ess--last-region-end)
    (ess-eval-region ess--last-region-beg
                     ess--last-region-end toggle)))
```